# how do I transform this object to look like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the value of an object that is in an array that is nested in an object. I don't even know if I explained how nested it is well enough...

here is what it looks like

```
{
     household and furniture: [{…}, {…}],
    school stuffs: [{…}, {…}]
}
```

so, I tried to map through it and got my code to look like this now..

```
{
      0: {school stuffs: [{…}, {…}]},
      1: {household and furniture:[{…}, {…}]}
}
```

how do I get the data to look the exact way it was initially **(without the 0 and 1 as keys)** after I edit the field

here is the code I used to edit the field

```
 const checkAll = e => {
    const newArray = Object.keys(productArray).map(elem => {
      return {[elem]: productArray[elem].map(innerElem => {
        return { ...innerElem, completed: e.target.checked }
      }) }
    })
    console.log({...newArray})
    setProductArray(newArray)
    
  }
```

Comment: keys names `household and furniture`, `school stuffs`, are just an example? I mean, as far as I know, blank spaces are not allowed (at least, not without quotes).

Comment: Yeah, they are just examples

Answer (score 2):

You are using `map` which essentially returns an `Array` and you're expecting an `Object`. When you spread using `{...newArray}`, it spreads the array using the indices as keys for the resulting object, hence, the `0` and `1`.
You can ideally use a `reduce` to return an object, and use it directly.

```
const checkAll = e => {
    const obj = Object.keys(productArray).reduce((acc, curr) => {
       acc[curr] = [...productArray[curr].map(item => ({...item, completed: e.target.checked}));
       return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log(obj);
    setProductArray(obj)
    
  }
```

Comment: I just ran the code, rn it looks like this 
`{school stuffs: {…}, household and furniture: {…}}`, I want it to look like this 
`{school stuffs: Array(2), household and furniture: Array(2)}`....Thanks a lot

Comment: I edited the line in the code to this and it worked.
      `acc[curr] = [...productArray[curr].map(item => ({...item, completed: e.target.checked})) ];`
Edit your answer, so I'll tick it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in single line:

```js
const obj ={household and furniture: [{…}, {…}],school stuffs:[{…},{…}]
}

let flatObj = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {});
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, the given was still like the former....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Can you make thing like that

```js
const example = { hello : {name : "kareem"} , example : [1,2] }

const converter = (inp)=>{
  return Object.assign({},Object.keys(inp).map(key=> {return {[key] : inp[key]}}))
}

console.log(converter(example))
```